# geojsonio::geojson_read error for a geojson file "conversion from feature type sfc_GEOMETRY to sp is not supported"

Tags: r, geospatial, geojson, geojsonio

I downloaded a geojson file of Iraq's electrical grid from EnergyData. You can download the file yourself here:

https://development-data-hub-s3-public.s3.amazonaws.com/ddhfiles/145188/electric-network-iraq.geojson

and visit the webpage here:

https://energydata.info/dataset/iraq-electricity-transmission-network-2017/resource/4a302ef4-0d79-47db-b301-7b40293067b0

I tried to use the library geojsonio to read the file into R, but:

When I set the `what` argument to `what = "sp"` it returns the error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': conversion from feature type sfc_GEOMETRY to sp is not supported

When I set `what = "list"` I get the error:

> Error in rcpp_sf_to_geojson(sf, digits, factors_as_string) :
> Unknown R object type

When I set `what = "json"` I get the error:

> Error in read_json(x, parse, what, stringsAsFactors, ...) :
> what='json' not supported for file and url inputs yet

Here's my code:

```
library(geojsonio)
obj = geojson_read("Filepath/electric-network-iraq.geojson"),
             what = "sp")
```

I tried alternate code, which just returned an empty string:

```
library(spData)
obj = system.file("Filepath/electric-network-iraq.geojson",package="spData")
```

I know the file isn't actually empty because when I open the file up in Notepad I can see the coordinates of the electrical grid.

This is my first time ever dealing with the geojsonio package, so please be detailed in your response. I just want to read in the powerlines into R as a lines spatial object, but I'm new to these data formats.

Comment: It is helpful to start with a link to the actual data download, rather than the html info page above, perhaps edit to reflect `https://development-data-hub-s3-public.s3.amazonaws.com/ddhfiles/145188/electric-network-iraq.geojson`, then see what issues come up...

Comment: The file could be malformed. I'm getting the same errors, and calling `geojsonlint::geojson_validate` on the file says it has an incomplete last line. Geojson has specific characteristics beyond regular json formatting, and sometimes files get labelled as geojson that are actually just json; `jsonlite::read_json` can read the file

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to read in the file with `read_json`. Follow-up question: with `read_json` the object is now of type list, so I can't plot it or crop it. I tried indexing into the object's features and using `SpatialLinesDataFrame` to make it a spatial object, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I posted part 2 of my question (converting object to spatial lines data frame) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523047/convert-json-object-to-spatial-lines-data-frame